# Why does this C program go pear-shaped? Have I broken my buffers?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I've been experimenting with C a little bit. I usually use PHP and javascript.

I did "Hello World" and then I typed in this, which I copied from a website somewhere...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 20
int intcmp(const void*v1, const void *v2){
    return (*(int *)v1 - *(int *)v2);
}
main(){
    int arr[MAX], count, key , *ptr;
    printf("Enter %d integer values; press enter after each\n", MAX);
    for (count = 0; count < MAX; count++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[count]);
    puts("Press a key to sort the values");
    getc(stdin);

    qsort(arr, MAX, sizeof(arr[0]), intcmp);

    for(count=0; count < MAX; count++)
        printf("\narr[%d] = %d.", count, arr[count]);

    puts("\nPress a key to continue");
    getc(stdin);

    printf("Enter a val to search for");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    ptr = (int * )bsearch(&key, arr, MAX, sizeof(arr[0]), intcmp);

    if(ptr != NULL){
        int fred =  (ptr - arr);
        printf("%d found at arr[%d]", key ,fred);
    }else{
        printf("%d not found", key);
    }
}
```

So far so good. I'm trying to understand what all the stars do, but it's falling into place (ha ha - falling stars :)

However, if I type in a float e.g. 21.45 when it asks me for 20 integers, it rushes through to "Enter a val to search for" having filled the 20 array values with weird numbers.

Have I created some sort of buffer overflow? I realise that input should be checked - but I'm interested to know what I've done. Could I use my program to run arbitrary code? (Well, no, not with my knowledge... but could someone?)

Comment: You must never discard the return value of an input operation (such as your `scanf`). Don't even bother looking anywhere else until you fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, if I type in a float e.g. 21.45 when it asks me for 20 integers, it rushes through to "Enter a val to search for" having filled the 20 array values with weird numbers

If you enter a value such as `21.45` the call to `scanf("%d")` will fail, as it is not an `int`, and will leave the `.45` in `stdin` (the `21` will be extracted as a valid `int`) to be processed again. This causes the loop to re-read this value again and again (as it fails every time). The weird numbers are due to the elements of the array being uninitialised.

Check the return value of `scanf()` which returns the number of assignments made and if it fails skip whatever is in `stdin`:

```
int count = 0;
while (count < MAX)
{
    if (1 == scanf("%d", &arr[count]))
    {
        count++; /* OK, so get next. */
    }
    else
    {
        /* !OK, skip invalid input. */
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Why does the array get different values if I enter different numbers?

Comment: @Pete, I am unsure what you mean? If `scanf()` fails the elements of the array are uninitialised meaning they can contain anything.

Comment: I can see the int value of my float, but the other 19 elements of the array are about half zeroes and half (apparently) random integers.

Answer (score 2):

If you fill the standard input with something that's not in the right format (in this case a float), the extraction of the value will fail. However, the broken data won't get extracted from the input stream. This means that `scanf` will fail repeatedly. As such, your `arr[0...MAX-1]` is not filled at all by scanf.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a float, then in the scanf you need to have:

```
scanf("%f", &arr[count]);
```

Additionally, you need to declare your array as `float arr[MAX]`